# What is the projection system used in Bhunaksha Rajasthan?

Tags: geospatial, india

I am trying to get the survey number details from [Bhunaksha website](https://bhunaksha.raj.nic.in/) . The website shows the coordinates on the top left corner, when I move cursor over a land record. I am able to find projection system of the coordinates displayed on top left corner.

Can anyone help me in this ?